# Why does Nicole Kidman not look like Nicole Kidman in The Hours?

Tags: the-hours

The first time I saw a *The Hours* poster I didn't recognize Nicole Kidman's face.

[image]

I thought her face changes according to the movie plot. Then I saw the movie and she looks really different during the whole movie. There is nothing related to the face I FOUND.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190418092941/https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0f/Nicole_K_Face.PNG/170px-Nicole_K_Face.PNG))</sub>

Why does Nicole Kidman not look like Nicole Kidman in this movie?

Comment: Because you're used to seeing with more makeup and/or bigger hair?

Comment: @OrangeDog or without a big prosthetic nose?

Comment: This is actually an interesting question with a very insightful answer.

Comment: Answer: Makeup.  Ever seen the movie "Monster"?  They turned Charlize Theron into one of the homliest people you've ever seen, and that couldn't have been easy.

Comment: There's nothing related to the face that you found?  I'm curious as to how you looked.  It's an easy Google search.

Comment: Why does Kenny Baker not look like human at all in "Star Wars"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### To look more like the character.

The reasons are, according to [Stephen Holden](https://www.nytimes.com/2003/02/15/movies/the-nose-was-the-final-straw.html),

> Stephen Holden said the makeup gave Ms. Kidman an ''uncanny physical resemblance'' to Woolf

[image]
<sub>(source: [britannica.com](https://media1.britannica.com/eb-media/82/138382-004-B5A1FC71.jpg))</sub>

As to how they made her look so different, from [here](http://www.zimbio.com/Many+Faces+-+Actors+Who%27ve+Worn+Prosthetic+Makeup/articles/ZLlqI5GGJoJ/Nicole+Kidman+The+Hours):

> Nicole Kidman donned a prosthetic nose to become Virginia Woolf in Stephen Daldry's The Hours

And [here](https://www.sfgate.com/entertainment/article/Hours-of-makeup-for-Kidman-2743177.php):

> Talk about a tough job. Makeup artists had to transform Nicole Kidman into the homely novelist Virginia Woolf for "The Hours," a task that took three hours a day. The key was a large prosthetic nose that rendered Kidman virtually unrecognizable.